# Update constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I can't install new version of constraint layout and other Repository like CardView and RecyclerView

my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.radin.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7'
}
```

I don't see new version of constraint layout in my SDK manager
[Screen shot of my sdk Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myb5T.jpg)

When i click on Install Repository and sync project nothing happens [Screen shot of my android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GiXW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try click in install repository and sync Project and change:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

And remove this from the build gradle file:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Comment: see my updated answer probably is the last thing making conflict with libs